# groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: ApplicationVariantData.getName()

Tags: android, gradle-kotlin-dsl

This question has been asked a lot of times on SO, but I was not able to find any solution that could work for me.
I am trying to migrate from groovy to kotlin DSL and getting the following error.

All the conversion is done into kotlin DSL, but when I am trying to sync the issue starts to appear. I am using the latest version of android gradle plugin.

```
 A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.
   Failed to notify project evaluation listener.
com.android.build.gradle.internal.crash.ExternalApiUsageException: groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: com.android.build.gradle.internal.variant.ApplicationVariantData.getName() is applicable for argument types: () values: []
 Possible solutions: getAt(java.lang.String), getClass()
KotlinJvmAndroidCompilation with name 'debug' not found.
```

Please let me know what can be done in this, Thanks in advance.

```js
plugins {
    id("com.android.application")
    id("com.google.firebase.crashlytics")
    id("io.hansel.preprocessor")
    id("com.google.firebase.firebase-perf")
    kotlin("android")
    kotlin("android.extensions")
    kotlin("kapt")
    id("com.google.gms.google-services")
}

buildscript {
    apply("../buildSrc/config.gradle.kts")
}

repositories {
    maven { url = uri(Config.Repositories.hansel_io) }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        flatDir {
            dirs("libs")
        }
    }
}
android {
    signingConfigs {
    ....
    }
}
defaultConfig {
...
}

buildTypes {
      getByName("debug") {
      ...
      }
      getByName("release") {
      ...
      }
}

flavorDimensions("version")
productFlavors {
    create("development") {
    ...
    }
    
    applicationVariants.all {
        val variant = this
        variant.outputs
            .map { it as BaseVariantOutputImpl }
            .forEach { output ->
                ....
            }
    }

}
    
compileOptions {
      targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
      sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
}

buildFeatures {
    dataBinding = true
}
```

Comment: if u could post your gradle file that could help

Comment: @siva I have added the code snippet, let me know if that helps.